# How to get the exit code of the failed command from remote ssh using jenkinsfile and parameterized build

Tags: ssh, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, remote-server

I am trying to build pipeline using Jenkinsfile to perform some action on remote server and want to get the exit code of the failed commands before moving ahead in other commands. I have tried in the following way but it always retrun 0 instead of 1 even if the command fails to execute or even if there is any exception in the execution.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
stage('stage') {
             when {
                expression {env.GIT_BRANCH == 'origin/stage'}
            }
            steps {
                echo 'build '
                ansiColor('xterm') {
                    echo 'build '
                    sh """ssh -tt server_address << EOF
                    cd /u/${DIR}
                    echo \$?
                    if [ \$? eq 1 ]; then
                        exit
                    fi
                    ls -al
                    exit
                    EOF"""
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $?
if [ $? eq 1 ]; then
```

The second `$?` would be the result of the previous `echo` command: most likely 0, considering the `echo` would have succeeded.

You would need to store the output of the first $? first:

```
cd /u/${DIR}
res=\$?
if [ \${res} eq 1 ]; then    
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I have tried your answer but still the issue persists cd /u/test- -bash: cd: /u/test-: No such file or directory res=0 from given command as the directory is not available, the result should contain 1 as the code of the command, because this command has failed, but it is returning 0, so I am unable to exit the build on failure.

Comment: @HassanIqbalKhan Can you add `set -x` before the `cd`? That way, we can see exactly what is executed and its result.